Does avoiding vaccination help avoid myocarditis?
The picture that emerges from this 2022 article by Voleti et al https://doi.org/10.3389/fcvm.2022.951314 is that the unvaccinated are 7 times as likely to get myocarditis than the vaccinated.  For the unvaccinated who get Covid, apparently about 1% get myocarditis.  Thus out of a group of 700 vaccinated persons, about 1 will get myocarditis.
If we assume that with the current rates of immunity present in the general population, (at most) 10% will eventually get Covid, we get the following picture.  Out of a group of 7000 unvaccinated persons, 700 will eventually get Covid, and therefore about 7 will get myocarditis.  Meanwhile, out of a group of 7000 vaccinated persons, about 10 will get myocarditis according to Voleti et al.  It emerges that a vaccinated person has an about 40% increased chance of contracting myocarditis than an unvaccinated person.
Therefore under the present conditions of existing immunity in the general population, if I want to minimize the risk of getting myocarditis, I should not get vaccinated (obviously this does not take into account other risks of Covid, and is not meant as a policy recommendation).  Is this analysis correct?

Can you point me to where you get that 40% figure?

@CareyGregory, modulo the assumptions I have stated, 10 vaccinated individuals will get myocarditis, whereas only 7 unvaccinated will get it.  The increase from 7 to 10 is about 40%.

The 10% chance of infection estimate seems extremely optimistic to me, what is the basis for that? Neither infections nor vaccines confer sterilizing immunity, so the present conditions of existing immunity in the general population aren't really relevant.

I agree with @Michael's answer. You're comparing different groups.

I am not sure what you mean when you claim that "the present
conditions of existing immunity in the general population aren't
really relevant."  The higher the vaccination rate (and/or percentage
of people who already got Covid), the less the risk of contracting
Covid.  I agree with you that neither the vaccine nor Covid itself
confer immunity.  If we assume for example that they are effective for
a year in preventing additional infections.  Then we would have to
evaluate what percentage of (unvaccinated) people are going to get
Covid in the next year. ...

... It seems clear that such a percentage in the US is lower than 10%.
Surely 30 million people are not going to contract Covid in the US
during the next year. @times

@CareyGregory, I am not really comparing any groups.  I just introduced the 7000 figure to get round numbers in the answers.  The point is that a single individual in a society that currently has a high rate of immunity has a choice of whether to get vaccinated or not.  As far as the narrow issue of myocarditis is concerned, it seems that she has a higher chance of getting it if she gets vaccinated than if she does not.

@MikhailKatz For Covid, the protection an unvaccinated individual gets from general population immunity is not large, because immunity protects against disease but does not prevent infection or spread of the virus. If you look at the US CDC's wastewater monitoring, for example, levels of circulating virus are 'very high'. If you go out in public, you will be exposed to the virus, and if you have no immunity, you will be infected, with a nearly 100% chance. I think you are severely underestimating the number of cases; remember that while most are asymptomatic, these still spread virus.

@times, I don't really follow your reasoning.  Covid has been with us for almost 5 years.  The situation with high wastewater levels has probably been around for at least half of that time.  By your logic, either everybody would have gotten infected already, or there should be very high levels of infection at this time - a situation we are not currently witnessing.  I should add that my question is not meant as epidemiological advice; only comparing the figures with respect to the narrow issue of myocarditis.

No - you're comparing different groups. If you take a cohort of patients with no exposure to Covid and no prior immunisation, the immunity will be zero - the lifetime risk of contracting Covid in this group will be higher than 10% - given that re-infections also occur, the number of Covid infections in your theoretical population of 7000 people will be higher than 700.

The question states explicitly that we are working under the assumption "under the present conditions of existing immunity in the general population".  Your hypothetical situation of a cohort of unvaccinated patients is not the situation envisioned in the question.  The question involves an analysis of unvaccinated individuals dispersed in a society with high level of immunity due to vaccination.  If one looks at the numbers for the US, for example, one will probably find that fewer than 10% will get infected, but I haven't researched the precise figures yet.
